# codeigniter only pages to an existing website

Tags: php, codeigniter

My website structure somewhat looks like below

```
css/
lib/
js/
index.php
profile.php
products.php
checkout.php
orders.php
invoice.php
```

I have added a codeigniter folder in there ...

```
codeigniter/application/
codeigniter/application/controllers/
codeigniter/application/controllers/mycontroller.php
and other files
```

I can access CodeIgniter stuff by going to `mywebsite.com/codeigniter/mycontroller` etc fine.

However, I want to get rid of `/codeigniter/` part from the URL. So I was wondering if it is possible to create a whitelist of the files which are CodeIgniter specific? For example, if the URL is mywebsite.com/mycontroller then it does CI stuff otherwise it looks for the plain PHP code file. I have only a couple of CI controllers and loads other non-CI files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Everything is done through the `index.php` file. Please refer to the manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Yes I know. What do I need to change in there in index.php to get the above setup working?

Comment: Alternatively you could just migrate your existing site to use codeigniter. If you're going to use a framework for part of your site it might be easier to use it for the whole thing. At least maintaing it would be consistent

Comment: Yes I'd love to migrate but that's lots of work. If I could get the above working then I would migrate page by page as required (and when I get time), if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use `.htaccess` to rewrite URL's that don't contain `.php`, `css`, `lib` and `js`. Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\.php|css|js|lib)$
RewriteRule (.*) codeigniter/index.php/$1
```

So:

```
http://example.com/css/test.css
```

stays

```
http://example.com/css/test.css
```

(as will all requests to css|lib|js. You can append more things here for the rewrite to ignore)

```
http://example.com/controller/method
```

becomes

```
http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/controller/method
```

You can test it out here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

More on rewriting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

**Short-term Solution**

You can start by simply converting the `index.php` file into a controller and name it whatever you wish:

```
<?php
class New_default_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        // home page stuff here
    }
}
```

Alter the `route.php` file and set your default controller so that simply visiting your site will trigger the proper controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'new_default_controller';
```

Apply the instructions for Removing the [index.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) file

Now calls to www.mysite.com/profile.php will access the `profile.php` at your root and calls to www.mysite.com/new_future_page will call your new_future_page controller.

Please let me know if any of this is confusing or you get stuck.

**Optimal Solution**

I wanted to leave a comment above but this would have been impossible to show as a comment.

You will have to take your PHP files and put them in the `controllers` folder like this:

```
codeigniter/application/controllers/profile.php
codeigniter/application/controllers/products.php
codeigniter/application/controllers/checkout.php
codeigniter/application/controllers/orders.php
codeigniter/application/controllers/invoice.php
```

Please go through and do the [Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html) before continuing any further. Specifically the [Static Pages](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) section will help you in achieving your goal.

You will have to convert your current PHP files to follow the flow of CodeIgniter

Comment: "You will have to convert your current PHP files to follow the flow of CodeIgniter" .... this is exactly what I am trying to avoid i.e. I don't have to convert all the files as there are a lot more files than the above listed. Coverting is gonna take me a good 2-3 weeks which I can't commit.

Comment: Yes I need short-term solution for now so let me try the above.

Comment: Sorry about the initial answer. I was not aware that there were far more pages than what you listed. I have been thoroughly enjoying CodeIgniter so I wish you Good Luck with it!